# Why change NGINX file locations?

Tags: linux, nginx, docker

Almost every example I have seen, of people configuring NGINX (mostly with Docker), changes the default file and folder locations.  Can someone think of a legitimate reason for this **other than personal preference** (ex: moving to the industry recognized location for such items)?

Two of the example changes I am seeing are...

**1. HTML Location (Root)**
The HTML root is being replaced from ...

```
/use/share/nginx/html/
```

... to ...

```
RUN mkdir /srv/www
COPY static-content /srv/www
```

**2. Logs Location**
Common log locations are replaced from ...

```
/var/log/nginx/
/var/log/nginx/error.log
/var/log/nginx/access.log
```

... to ...

```
RUN mkdir /etc/nginx/logs \
    && touch /etc/nginx/logs/static.log \
    && touch /etc/nginx/logs/error.log \
    && touch /etc/nginx/logs/access.log
```

I'm certainly no expert on etiher Docker nor the Linux file system.  I'm just curious if there is some benefit to doing this... again, other than personal preference.

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/656430/difference-between-var-www-and-srv-www-in-nginx I'd say the first answer addresses this question, too.

Comment: None of the official docker images for nginx moves the logs to /etc. Where did you get that Dockerfile from?

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer: The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) for UNIX-like operating systems suggests that data served by the system is to be found in `/srv`.

Why someone would move log files to `/etc`, which is often recommended to be mounted read-only for security-reasons, I don't understand. Hopefully someone else can shed some light on this!

Comment: There is no posix specification about logfiles location. /etc looks weird, but its name comes from etcetera, as everything without a specification could go there.